# How do I disable pastying into my xterm?

Tags: xterm, paste, linux-terminal

Many times I have accedentally pasted into my Xterm window, with the result that whatever text is pasted in is executed by my shell (zsh). I would like  to know if I can disable pasting into Xterm.

Edit: it is my middle mouse button that is doing the pasting. I would rather avoid pasting into the Xterm with my mouse, since Ctrl - Shift - V is both faster and less error-prone.

Comment: I suppose you still want to paste in other locations?  Have you considered simply re-mapping, or un-mapping the paste button?

Comment: @Zoredache How would one do this? The paste button is the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the safe-paste plugin for oh-my-zsh. This prevents anything pasted from being executed until I hit enter, so I can Ctrl-C and discard what I pasted.

Edit: This apparently does not work completely, because I could paste text (containing an embedded escape sequence) that would fool zsh. So I am back to the original question: How do I disable entirely pasting into my Xterm with the mouse? (The solution in general is to first look at everything in a text editor, but I want to avoid accidental pasting).